# postgresql: how modify pg_catalog with a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Hi I want create a function that creates a table in the pg_catalog like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE

BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE pg_catalog.tab(a integer)';   
        RETURN;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.tab"
DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.

**I edit my question for add more detail:**

Real I want create a function that start when a table was dropped. The only way that I think was to create a trigger on table pg_catalog.tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

  EXECUTE 'CREATE TRIGGER "tt_drop" BEFORE DELETE ON pg_catalog.pg_tables EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.b()';
  RETURN;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and in the function b I want to do some operation on drop table before it was dropped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is prohibited from practical and mainly security reasons - pg_catalog is first on search path always and nobody can change it simply because PostgreSQL team expects so functions from pg_catalog will not be overwritten by custom functions.

Some very ugly tricks exists, but I don't advice to use it.

Little bit less ugly, but still very ugly is switch Postgres to single mode - there any security mechanism are off - but there is high risk of database damage. So only persons with perfect knowledge of Postgres internals should to use it.

**Reply to updated question:**

You cannot to create trigger on system tables. But There are [event triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html) and it is probably it what you want (supported by PostgreSQL 9.3).

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_event_trigger_for_drops()
        RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '% dropped object: % %.% %',
                     tg_tag,
                     obj.object_type,
                     obj.schema_name,
                     obj.object_name,
                     obj.object_identity;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER test_event_trigger_for_drops
   ON sql_drop
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_event_trigger_for_drops();

postgres=# DROP TABLE obce CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to materialized view obce_stredocesky_kraj
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: table public.obce public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: index public.obce_okres_id_idx public.obce_okres_id_idx
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: table constraint public.<NULL> obce_okres_id_fk on public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: trigger <NULL>.<NULL>  "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_46471" on public.okresy
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: trigger <NULL>.<NULL> "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_46472" on public.okresy
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: trigger <NULL>.<NULL> "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_46473" on public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: trigger <NULL>.<NULL> "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_46474" on public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: sequence public.obce_id_seq public.obce_id_seq
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: type public.obce_id_seq public.obce_id_seq
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: default value <NULL>.<NULL> for public.obce.id
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: table constraint public.<NULL> _obce_pkey on public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: index public._obce_pkey public._obce_pkey
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: materialized view public.obce_stredocesky_kraj public.obce_stredocesky_kraj
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: index public.obce_stredocesky_kraj_nazev_idx public.obce_stredocesky_kraj_nazev_idx
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: type public.obce_stredocesky_kraj public.obce_stredocesky_kraj
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: type public._obce_stredocesky_kraj public.obce_stredocesky_kraj[]
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: rule <NULL>.<NULL> "_RETURN" on public.obce_stredocesky_kraj
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: type public.obce public.obce
NOTICE:  DROP TABLE dropped object: type public._obce public.obce[]
DROP TABLE
```

see

- http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-event-triggers/
- http://www.depesz.com/2012/07/29/waiting-for-9-3-event-triggers/
- http://www.jcdba.com/exploring-postgresql-9-3-event-triggers/

Comment: thanks very interesting but I need the name of the dropped table and the TG_OBJECTNAME is now not supported! In the future i will modify my function usign event trigger.  Now I found allow_system_table_mods = on to add to postgres.conf but how do you tell me it's not a right mode :-(  If I active it only when I create the trigger and disactive it after, the trigger work the same?

Comment: @user3297525: dropped table name is known - see updated reply

Comment: ok but the dropped table can't be moved to another schema ( alter table t  set schema s) because table t doesn't exist now for postgres. how can I fire the trigger before the drop action?

Comment: Probably you cannot to do it. This is too hard harakiri. If you need to do some more complex operation with database structure, then application level is better than triggers.